# Image not showing in full size Bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Somehow my image carousel don't show anything. It's supposed to show a full sized image. If I don't set DOCTYPE to html5, it works just fine. Any ideas from looking at the source?

http://putten.evisio.no/

Comment: are you using `width:100%` in `<img>`

Comment: I'm not using img to show the image. I'm setting background image in a full sized div (check line 136).

Comment: I think posting you code would be good instead of just adding external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height: 100%;` rule in your child theme's CSS @ line 164.
And add

```
.carousel-inner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#myCarousel {
 min-height: 100vh; 
}
```

to it.

Comment: Yes, that's for the content below the carousel.

Comment: I have added slides? First one at line 135, with a background image. If I remove height 100%, it will not fill the page.

Comment: Updated again. If you want your carousel to be 100% of device height add `#myCarousel {min-height: 100vh; }` to your CSS.